# Failing to properly update one MYSQL table with corresponding data from another

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Currently, my task is to update the *Place1* column in my *mkindex* table, with the corresponding *mkplace_id* value in the *mkplace* table. This seemed simple enough, but I must be misunderstanding something or missing some detail.

*The desired result would be storing the corresponding mkplace_id in place of mkindex.Place1*

I began by trying variations on this:

`UPDATE mkindex
INNER JOIN mkplace ON mkindex.Place1 = mkplace.mkplace_name
SET mkindex.Place1 = mkplace.mkplace_id`

This does not have the effect I want it to have. The inner join itself actually matches *some* of the *Place1 = mkplace_name*, but absolutely not all expected matches. It returns some 117 matches, out of the hundreds of thousands that it should return, and furthermore it doesn't actually set any rows with *mkindex.Place1* to *mkplace.mkplace_name*.

This led me to try a few other methods, including:

`UPDATE mkindex 
SET mkindex.Place1 = (
    SELECT mkplace_id 
    FROM mkplace 
    WHERE mkindex.Place1 = mkplace.mkplace_name 
    LIMIT 1
)`

The number of *matches* seem to be around the right number, but it just replaces every instance of *Place1* with NULL.

Am I overlooking something obvious? I also considered it being due to collation, so I have also tried running this before the query:

`ALTER TABLE mkplace CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci`

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated, I'm more confused than anything at this point.

---

**mkindex** *(latin1_general_ci)*

[image: mkindex description]

---

**mkplace**
    *(utf8_general_ci)*

[image: mkplace description]

Comment: Update joins that return multiple matches may overwrite each other such as *Place1* values that repeat. Check the `SELECT` version of that `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first query looks fine, I'm going to go out on a limb and suggest that there may only be 117 rows where mkindex.Place1 is actually equal to mkplace.mkplace_name. Machines don't lie. You could add a TRIM() around each column but I doubt that will help. To get an idea what you're dealing with try analyzing mkindex first.

```html
SELECT 
  mkindex.Place1,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  mkindex
GROUP BY 
  mkindex.Place1;
```

Comment: TRIM() has increased the number of matches dramatically, I never noticed the frequency of whitespace characters before and after Place1. This should at least bring me closer to the solution.

Are there any other functions that could help clean up this data?

Also, does comparing between utf8 and latin1 strings make a difference here? (I converted uft8 to latin1 anyways, but only curious)

Comment: The character encoding might cause problems, but probably only if you are dealing with other languages which it looks like you aren't. Always a good idea to have consistency though.